# How to approximate a retarded interaction by an instantaneous one?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

I'm now having a retarded interaction (in terms of imaginary time) of the form:
$$-\frac{1}{2\mathcal{V} \rho_{\varphi}}\int d\tau_{1}d\tau_{2}\sum_{k,k'}\frac{1}{2\Omega_{k-k'}}
e^{-\Omega_{k-k'}|\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}|} \bar{\chi}_{k}(\tau_{1})
\bar{\chi}_{-k}(\tau_{2})
\chi_{-k'}(\tau_{2}) \chi_{k'}(\tau_{1})$$
However, I want to do a mean field analysis of this interaction and I need to approximate this retarded interaction by an instantaneous one, i.e., to get something like:
$$\int d\tau \sum_{k,k'}V_{k,k'}\bar{\chi}_{k}(\tau)
\bar{\chi}_{-k}(\tau)
\chi_{-k'}(\tau) \chi_{k'}(\tau)$$
So I want to ask is there any standard way to estimate the form of $V_{k,k'}$ above? I know this problem is in some sence equivalent to the phonon-mediated electron-electron interaction in BCS problem, but I couldn't find any reference on how to approximate the value of coupling "constant" from the retarded one. What I see from many text books just give a simple form like $-V_0$ when the electron excitation energy is smaller than the Debye frequency, without showing the exact dependence of $V_0$ on the original phonon frequency and electron-phonon couplings.

Hope someone familiar with this issue can give some suggestions, any recommendations on relevant references are also welcome.